# How to show seven results?

Tags: mobile

I'm working on a bike rental website (mobile). 
In this project there are seven shops and I need a "locations page" where the user can click on the "get distance" button to enable GPS and obtain the walking distance between them and the shop.

Right now, the user can navigate through the different shops by clicking the arrows below the map. 
I was thinking about a sort of "slide to discover" solution but this seems not to be so intuitive (the target is very wide).

What's a good solution to show these seven results?

Let me know if I missed something in the description, thanks.

[image: Location]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution for this problem (map first, no filter system etc.) by replying to the other users. Looks good.

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

I think shop pictures should go to top and location should come below the get distance button.

Flow should be like below:

1. user sees all 7 shops on top first with sliding buttons.
2. user may select one of the shops using your next and previous
   buttons.(avoid sliding action as this makes user to think that he is
   selecting one of the shops rather he is just browsing them.)
3. user sees get distance CTA button.
4. user clicks on CTA.
5. then your page slides down to show user the location for active shop and
   displays corresponding information.

Comment: Hi. Are you talking about buttons like the carousel slider? It could be good but the map is the main item. I can't place the picture on top because it should help the potential client just to recognize the shop (they are new in town) after finding the closest one. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggest instead of the arrows a single button "Shops list" that will display all the selectable shops in the area (in a modal box).

Can we ask for the closest shop from where we are ? Do we have to call the get_distance_from_where_i_am for each shop to know which one is the nearest ?

Is the button "get distance" really good UX if you have to click on it everytime you select a shop ?

Comment: Hi. I avoided the "shops list" button because this site is oriented to foreign tourists and they don't want to select many times to compare, they just want to know the distance (besides, they need to remember the name in a different language and this could be a problem). Then, good question about "which one is the nearest". The answer is no, we have just to click one time and the "get distance" button will disappear if the GPS is enabled. I just thought about a solution, maybe a toggle button to enable and disable the GPS could work well. What do you think? Thanks.